# Declare commands that can only be used inside others commands

Tags: macros

I am new to Latex and I am creating my own CV class.

I want to be able to use commands I create in my class inside other commands, so they can be grouped around specific topics. Here is one snippet I created to ilustrate what I want to accomplish:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{my-cv}

\CVInfo{
  \FirstName{myFirstName}
  \LastName{myLastName}
  \Email{myEmail}
  \Phone{myPhone}
  \Picture{myPicture}
  \RoundedPictureOptions{
    \PictureScale{0.4}
    \PictureXShift{-0.1cm}
    \PictureYShift{-0.4cm}
    \PictureBorder{
      \PictureBorderIsDashed{Y}
      \PictureBorderThickness{thick}
      \PictureBorderColor{blue}
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

As you can see, all information about the CV is inside the *\CVInfo* command, all information about the border of the picture is inside the *\PictureBorder* command, and so on.

Inside the class, these commands should only set some values to internal commands that would be used elsewhere:

```
\newcommand{\FirstName}[1]{
  \def\@firstName{#1}
}
```

To summarize, I want to the use of that commands to be strictly the way its shown in the code above, i.e., this:

```
\FirstName{myFirstName}
\CVInfo{
...
}
```

and this:

```
\CVInfo{
...
}
\FirstName{myFirstName}
```

should do nothing to the *\FirstName* command.

Is there a way to do this? Anyway, Im not quite sure if this is the approach I should take when creating my own class, so feel free to share any comment about a better way to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: I think one approach would be to have the `\CVInfo` macro set a switch, and then have the inside commands check for whether that switch is true. But I think the `pgfkeys` solution below is better.

Comment: What do you mean by "...should do nothing to the *\FirstName* command." ? Shall the command `\FirstName` not be executed and thus `\@firstName` not be redefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer a macro-interface to a key=value-interface, you can define commands `\FirstName`, `\LastName`, etc, to append to a token-register directives for redefining the internal macros. **If you do this, you need to make sure that within the .tex-input-file every line inside the optional argument of `\CVInfo` ends with either a comment-character or something that gets tokenized as a control-word-token. Otherwise undesired space-tokens and thus undesired horizontal glue might come into being at places where lines inside the argument of `\CVInfo` end with `}` or some other thing that does not get tokenized as a control-word-token.**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\newtoks\CVInfotoks
\newcommand\DefineDontUseTheCommandHereError[2]{%
  \renewcommand#1[1]{\DontUseTheCommandHereError{#1}{#2}}%
}%
\newcommand\DefineDontUseTheCommandOptHereError[2]{%
  \renewcommand#1[1][]{\DontUseTheCommandHereError{#1}{#2}}%
}%
\newcommand\DontUseTheCommandHereError[2]{%
  \ClassError{my-cv}{%
     You can't execute the command \string#1 within the argument of the command \string#2%
  }{%
     Executing the command \string#1 within the argument of the command \string#2 seems not to make sense.%
  }%
}%
% Initial values:
\newcommand*\MyCV@firstName{myFirstName}%
\newcommand*\MyCV@lastName{myLastName}%
\newcommand*\MyCV@Email{myEmail}%
\newcommand*\MyCV@Phone{myPhone}%
\newcommand*\MyCV@Picture{myPicture}%
\newcommand*\MyCV@PictureScale{0.4}%
\newcommand*\MyCV@PictureXShift{-0.1cm}%
\newcommand*\MyCV@PictureYShift{-0.4cm}%
\newcommand*\MyCV@PictureBorderIsDashed{Y}%
\newcommand*\MyCV@PictureBorderThickness{thick}%
\newcommand*\MyCV@PictureBorderColor{blue}%
%
\newcommand\CVInfo[1][]{%
  \begingroup
  \CVInfotoks{}%
  \DefineDontUseTheCommandOptHereError{\CVInfo}{\CVInfo}%
  \long\def\FirstName##1{\CVInfotoks=\expandafter{\the\CVInfotoks\def\MyCV@firstName{##1}}}%
  \long\def\LastName##1{\CVInfotoks=\expandafter{\the\CVInfotoks\def\MyCV@lastName{##1}}}%
  \long\def\Email##1{\CVInfotoks=\expandafter{\the\CVInfotoks\def\MyCV@Email{##1}}}%
  \long\def\Phone##1{\CVInfotoks=\expandafter{\the\CVInfotoks\def\MyCV@Phone{##1}}}%
  \long\def\Picture##1{\CVInfotoks=\expandafter{\the\CVInfotoks\def\MyCV@Picture{##1}}}%
  \newcommand\RoundedPictureOptions[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \DefineDontUseTheCommandOptHereError{\CVInfo}{\RoundedPictureOptions}%
    \DefineDontUseTheCommandHereError{\RoundedPictureOptions}{\RoundedPictureOptions}%
    \DefineDontUseTheCommandHereError{\FirstName}{\RoundedPictureOptions}%
    \DefineDontUseTheCommandHereError{\LastName}{\RoundedPictureOptions}%
    \DefineDontUseTheCommandHereError{\Email}{\RoundedPictureOptions}%
    \DefineDontUseTheCommandHereError{\Phone}{\RoundedPictureOptions}%
    \DefineDontUseTheCommandHereError{\Picture}{\RoundedPictureOptions}%
    \long\def\PictureScale####1{\CVInfotoks=\expandafter{\the\CVInfotoks\def\MyCV@PictureScale{####1}}}%
    \long\def\PictureXShift####1{\CVInfotoks=\expandafter{\the\CVInfotoks\def\MyCV@PictureXShift{####1}}}%
    \long\def\PictureYShift####1{\CVInfotoks=\expandafter{\the\CVInfotoks\def\MyCV@PictureYShift{####1}}}%
    \newcommand\PictureBorder[1]{%
      \begingroup
      \DefineDontUseTheCommandOptHereError{\CVInfo}{\PictureBorder}%
      \DefineDontUseTheCommandHereError{\RoundedPictureOptions}{\PictureBorder}%
      \DefineDontUseTheCommandHereError{\FirstName}{\PictureBorder}%
      \DefineDontUseTheCommandHereError{\LastName}{\PictureBorder}%
      \DefineDontUseTheCommandHereError{\Email}{\PictureBorder}%
      \DefineDontUseTheCommandHereError{\Phone}{\PictureBorder}%
      \DefineDontUseTheCommandHereError{\Picture}{\PictureBorder}%
      \DefineDontUseTheCommandHereError{\PictureBorder}{\PictureBorder}%
      \DefineDontUseTheCommandHereError{\PictureScale}{\PictureBorder}%
      \DefineDontUseTheCommandHereError{\PictureXShift}{\PictureBorder}%
      \DefineDontUseTheCommandHereError{\PictureYShift}{\PictureBorder}%
      \long\def\PictureBorderIsDashed########1{\CVInfotoks=\expandafter{\the\CVInfotoks\def\MyCV@PictureBorderIsDashed{########1}}}%
      \long\def\PictureBorderThickness########1{\CVInfotoks=\expandafter{\the\CVInfotoks\def\MyCV@PictureBorderThickness{########1}}}%
      \long\def\PictureBorderColor########1{\CVInfotoks=\expandafter{\the\CVInfotoks\def\MyCV@PictureBorderColor{########1}}}%
      ####1%
      \expandafter\endgroup
      \expandafter\CVInfotoks\expandafter=\expandafter{\the\CVInfotoks}%
    }%
    ##1%
    \expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\CVInfotoks\expandafter=\expandafter{\the\CVInfotoks}%
  }%
  #1%
  \expandafter\endgroup\the\CVInfotoks
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \message{%
    ^^J%
    Internal macros are now defined as follows:^^J%
    \string\MyCV@firstName: \meaning\MyCV@firstName^^J%
    \string\MyCV@lastName: \meaning\MyCV@lastName^^J%
    \string\MyCV@Email: \meaning\MyCV@Email^^J%
    \string\MyCV@Phone: \meaning\MyCV@Phone^^J%
    \string\MyCV@Picture: \meaning\MyCV@Picture^^J%
    \string\MyCV@PictureScale: \meaning\MyCV@PictureScale^^J%
    \string\MyCV@PictureXShift: \meaning\MyCV@PictureXShift^^J%
    \string\MyCV@PictureYShift: \meaning\MyCV@PictureYShift^^J%
    \string\MyCV@PictureBorderIsDashed: \meaning\MyCV@PictureBorderIsDashed^^J%
    \string\MyCV@PictureBorderThickness: \meaning\MyCV@PictureBorderThickness^^J%
    \string\MyCV@PictureBorderColor: \meaning\MyCV@PictureBorderColor^^J%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand\FirstName{Outside \string\CVInfo this command is totally different.}

\CVInfo

\CVInfo[%
  \FirstName{John}%
  \LastName{Doe}%
  \Picture{JohnDoe.jpg}%
  \RoundedPictureOptions{%
    % \LastName{Smith} % uncomment to see the error-message.
    % \CVInfo % uncomment to see the error-message.
    % \CVInfo[] % uncomment to see the error-message.
    \PictureScale{0.8}%
    \PictureYShift{0.8cm}%
    \PictureBorder{%
      \PictureBorderIsDashed{N}%
      \PictureBorderThickness{not so thick}%
      \PictureBorderColor{red}%
    }%
    \PictureXShift{0.6cm}%
  }%
  \Email{john\string@doe.com}%
  \Phone{123456}%
]%

\message{^^J\string\FirstName: \meaning\FirstName}
\message{^^J^^J\string\Email: \meaning\Email^^J^^J}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

When compiling the example above, the terminal provides the following messages:

```
$ pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))

Internal macros are now defined as follows:
\MyCV@firstName: macro:->myFirstName
\MyCV@lastName: macro:->myLastName
\MyCV@Email: macro:->myEmail
\MyCV@Phone: macro:->myPhone
\MyCV@Picture: macro:->myPicture
\MyCV@PictureScale: macro:->0.4
\MyCV@PictureXShift: macro:->-0.1cm
\MyCV@PictureYShift: macro:->-0.4cm
\MyCV@PictureBorderIsDashed: macro:->Y
\MyCV@PictureBorderThickness: macro:->thick
\MyCV@PictureBorderColor: macro:->blue


Internal macros are now defined as follows:
\MyCV@firstName: macro:->John
\MyCV@lastName: macro:->Doe
\MyCV@Email: macro:->john\string @doe.com
\MyCV@Phone: macro:->123456
\MyCV@Picture: macro:->JohnDoe.jpg
\MyCV@PictureScale: macro:->0.8
\MyCV@PictureXShift: macro:->0.6cm
\MyCV@PictureYShift: macro:->0.8cm
\MyCV@PictureBorderIsDashed: macro:->N
\MyCV@PictureBorderThickness: macro:->not so thick
\MyCV@PictureBorderColor: macro:->red


\FirstName: \long macro:->Outside \string \CVInfo this command is totally diffe
rent. 

\Email: undefined

(./test.aux) (./test.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Comment: Could you explain how does this work? `\long\def\FirstName##1{\CVInfotoks=\expandafter{\the\CVInfotoks\def\MyCV@firstName{##1}}}%`. I do not quite understand how the _MyCV@firstName_ macro gets the value I want to give it.

Comment: `\FirstName`'s argument `##1` becomes part of a set of tokens forming the directive `\def\MyCV@firstName{##1}`. The tokens forming that directive are appended to the contents of the token-register `\CVInfotoks`: TeX expands tokens while searching the opening curly brace of a token-register-assignment. Thus `\expandafter{\the\CVInfotoks...}` makes sure that the current content of `\CVInfotoks` ends up in the new token-register-assignment, too. When all appending to `\CVInfotoks` is done, `\CVInfotoks` is "flushed" via `\expandafter\endgroup\theCVInfotoks` at the end of carrying out `\CVInfo`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the package [pgfkeys](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeys) for setting up a key-val interface.

The package [pgfkeys](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeys) is a component of the packages [Ti*k*Z and pgf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

The package [pgfkeys](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeys) is explained in [Part VII: Utilities, section 88 - Key Management of pgfmanual.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#section.88). ([pgfmanual.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) is the manual for the packages [Ti*k*Z and pgf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).)

A starting-point could be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\MapNewCVInfoValueKeyToMacro[3]{%
  % #1 = key
  % #2 = initial definition text of internal macro
  % #3 = internal macro to define from value of key
  \@ifdefinable#3{%
    \pgfkeys{#1/.value required, #1/.store in=#3, #1=#2}%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\ifdashedborder{%
  \@ifdefinable\dashborderfalse{%
    \@ifdefinable\dashbordertrue{%
      \newif\ifdashedborder\dashedborderfalse
    }%
  }%
}%
\pgfkeys{%
  /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/dashed/.is if=dashedborder, 
     /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/dashed=true,
     /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/dashed/.value required,
  /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/.code=\pgfkeys{/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/.cd,#1},
    /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/.value required, 
  /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/.code=\pgfkeys{/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/.cd,#1},
    /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/.value required, 
}%
\MapNewCVInfoValueKeyToMacro{/CVInfo/first name}{myFirstName}{\@Firstname}
\MapNewCVInfoValueKeyToMacro{/CVInfo/last name}{myLastName}{\@Lastname}
\MapNewCVInfoValueKeyToMacro{/CVInfo/email}{myEmail}{\@Email}
\MapNewCVInfoValueKeyToMacro{/CVInfo/phone}{myPhone}{\@Phone}
\MapNewCVInfoValueKeyToMacro{/CVInfo/picture}{myPicture}{\@Picture}
\MapNewCVInfoValueKeyToMacro{/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/scale}{0.4}{\@Picturescale}
\MapNewCVInfoValueKeyToMacro{/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/x shift}{-0.1cm}{\@Picturexshift}
\MapNewCVInfoValueKeyToMacro{/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/y shift}{-0.4cm}{\@Pictureyshift}
\MapNewCVInfoValueKeyToMacro{/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/thickness}{thick}{\@Pictureborderthickness}
\MapNewCVInfoValueKeyToMacro{/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/color}{blue}{\@Picturebordercolor}

\newcommand\CVInfo[1][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/CVInfo/.cd,#1}%
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \message{%
    ^^J%
    Internal macros are now defined as follows:^^J%
    \string\@Firstname: \meaning\@Firstname^^J%
    \string\@Lastname: \meaning\@Lastname^^J%
    \string\@Email: \meaning\@Email^^J%
    \string\@Phone: \meaning\@Phone^^J%
    \string\@Picture: \meaning\@Picture^^J%
    \string\@Picturescale: \meaning\@Picturescale^^J%
    \string\@Picturexshift: \meaning\@Picturexshift^^J%
    \string\@Pictureyshift: \meaning\@Pictureyshift^^J%
    \string\ifdashedborder: \meaning\ifdashedborder^^J%
    \string\@Pictureborderthickness: \meaning\@Pictureborderthickness^^J%
    \string\@Picturebordercolor: \meaning\@Picturebordercolor^^J%
  }%
}%

\makeatother

\CVInfo

\CVInfo[%
  first name=John,
  last name=Doe,
  picture=JohnDoe.jpg,
  RoundedPictureOptions={
    scale=0.8,
    x shift=0.6cm,
    y shift=0.8cm,
    Border={
      dashed=false,
      thickness=not so thick,
      color=red
    }%
  },
  email=john\string@doe.com,
  phone=123456
]

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

When compiling the example above, the terminal will tell you the following:

```
$ pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex)))

Internal macros are now defined as follows:
\@Firstname: macro:->myFirstName
\@Lastname: macro:->myLastName
\@Email: macro:->myEmail
\@Phone: macro:->myPhone
\@Picture: macro:->myPicture
\@Picturescale: macro:->0.4
\@Picturexshift: macro:->-0.1cm
\@Pictureyshift: macro:->-0.4cm
\ifdashedborder: \iftrue
\@Pictureborderthickness: macro:->thick
\@Picturebordercolor: macro:->blue


Internal macros are now defined as follows:
\@Firstname: macro:->John
\@Lastname: macro:->Doe
\@Email: macro:->john\string @doe.com
\@Phone: macro:->123456
\@Picture: macro:->JohnDoe.jpg
\@Picturescale: macro:->0.8
\@Picturexshift: macro:->0.6cm
\@Pictureyshift: macro:->0.8cm
\ifdashedborder: \iffalse
\@Pictureborderthickness: macro:->not so thick
\@Picturebordercolor: macro:->red
(./test.aux) (./test.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

The so-called key-tree of the pgfkeys package also serves as a database for storing whatsoever pieces of data.

Instead of defining internal macros, you can use `\pgfkeysvalueof` for obtaining values of value-keys:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifdashedborder\dashedborderfalse
\pgfkeys{%
  /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/dashed/.is if=dashedborder, 
    /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/dashed=true, 
    /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/dashed/.value required, 
  /CVInfo/first name/.value required, /CVInfo/first name/.initial=myFirstName,
  /CVInfo/last name/.value required, /CVInfo/last name/.initial=myLastName,
  /CVInfo/email/.value required, /CVInfo/email/.initial=myEmail,
  /CVInfo/phone/.value required, /CVInfo/phone/.initial=myPhone,
  /CVInfo/picture/.value required, /CVInfo/picture/.initial=myPicture,
  /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/scale/.value required, /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/scale/.initial=0.4,
  /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/x shift/.value required, /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/x shift/.initial=-0.1cm,
  /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/y shift/.value required, /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/y shift/.initial=-0.4cm,
  /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/thickness/.value required, /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/thickness/.initial=thick,
  /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/color/.value required, /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/color/.initial=blue,
  /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/.code=\pgfkeys{/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/.cd,#1},
    /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/.value required,
  /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/.code=\pgfkeys{/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/.cd,#1},
    /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/.value required
}%

\newcommand\CVInfo[1][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/CVInfo/.cd,#1}%
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \message{%
    ^^J%
    Values of keys are set as follows:^^J%
    /CVInfo/first name=\pgfkeysvalueof{/CVInfo/first name}^^J%
    /CVInfo/last name=\pgfkeysvalueof{/CVInfo/last name}^^J%
    /CVInfo/email=\pgfkeysvalueof{/CVInfo/email}^^J%
    /CVInfo/phone=\pgfkeysvalueof{/CVInfo/phone}^^J%
    /CVInfo/picture=\pgfkeysvalueof{/CVInfo/picture}^^J%
    /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/scale=\pgfkeysvalueof{/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/scale}^^J%
    /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/x shift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/x shift}^^J%
    /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/y shift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/y shift}^^J%
    \string\ifdashedborder: \meaning\ifdashedborder^^J%
    /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/thickness=\pgfkeysvalueof{/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/thickness}^^J%
    /CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/color=\pgfkeysvalueof{/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/color}^^J%
  }%
}%

\makeatother

\CVInfo

\CVInfo[%
  first name=John,
  last name=Doe,
  picture=JohnDoe.jpg,
  RoundedPictureOptions={%
    scale=0.8,
    x shift=0.6cm,
    y shift=0.8cm,
    Border={%
      dashed=false,
      thickness=not so thick,
      color=red
    }%
  },
  email=john\string@doe.com,
  phone=123456
]

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

When compiling the example above, the terminal will tell you the following:

```
$ pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex)))

Values of keys are set as follows:
/CVInfo/first name=myFirstName
/CVInfo/last name=myLastName
/CVInfo/email=myEmail
/CVInfo/phone=myPhone
/CVInfo/picture=myPicture
/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/scale=0.4
/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/x shift=-0.1cm
/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/y shift=-0.4cm
\ifdashedborder: \iftrue
/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/thickness=thick
/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/color=blue


Values of keys are set as follows:
/CVInfo/first name=John
/CVInfo/last name=Doe
/CVInfo/email=john@doe.com
/CVInfo/phone=123456
/CVInfo/picture=JohnDoe.jpg
/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/scale=0.8
/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/x shift=0.6cm
/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/y shift=0.8cm
\ifdashedborder: \iffalse
/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/thickness=not so thick
/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/color=red
(./test.aux) (./test.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

You may wish to turn `/CVInfo/RoundedPictureOptions/Border/thickness` into a choice-key.